# Matrix with unit determinant as a product of elementary matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

There are three types of elementary matrices:

- Type 1: matrices obtained by interchanging the *i*th row of $I$ and *j*th row of $I$;
- Type 2: matrices obtained by multiplying the *i*th row of $I$ by $\lambda\neq 0$;
- Type 3: matrices obtained by adding $\lambda$ times the *j*th row of $I$ to the *i*th row of $I$.

I know that every invertible matrix $A$ can be written as a product of elementary matrices (of types 1, 2 and 3). According to Example 12.2.5 [here](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=y1DdmOLyQ9gC&pg=PA328&lpg=PA328&dq=matrices+with+%22determinant+1+is+path+connected%22&source=bl&ots=8-t6I0_Sdt&sig=SDuUvTmo5OpTpBMKCpsaijgUdlk&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=-sZYVY3-FYyegwT1w4CYDw&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=matrices%20with%20%22determinant%201%20is%20path%20connected%22&f=false), it is clear that

> (a) if $\det A=1$ then $A$ can be written as a product of elementary matrices of type 2 and type 3.
>
> (b) if $\det A=1$  and the factorization of $A$ (in terms of elementary matrices) has a matrix of type 2 with some $\lambda$, than this factorization also has a matrix of type 2 with $\lambda^{-1}$.

The item (b) is true because otherwise we would have $\det A\neq 1$. However, I can't understand why (a) is true. So, I'd like help to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: Take your matrix and apply Gaussian elimination, until you obtain the identity matrix. You will see that if the matrix has determinant $1$, you can reduce it applying only operations of type $3$ (so the case $a$ can even be improved, you don't need matrices of type $2$).

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

the determinat of a product of matrices is the product of the determinants, and an elementary matrix of type 1) has negative determinat (it is an alternating multilinear form).

Comment: For me, the first implication of your hint is: the number $k$ of matrices of type 1 in the factorization of $A$ is even. Why $k>0$ is not possible?